# Jquery Image/Video Carousel, centered with variable width items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I've been searching long and hard trying to find a jquery based slider/carousel. I need it to be able to handle a variable number of items, variable width items(images or videos). It also needs to show the prev and next items next to the centered current item so kinda like this ] [] [ if you get me haha. So the current item would be centered with like half the next and prev to the right and left.??

finding it very hard to find something like this.

any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Hmmm well that didn't gain much, please if anyone can help me out that would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you play a little with this plugin you can do what you want I'm 100% sure.
[Jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: So no, I can;t see how I could make this center the images as they always align to the left. thanks